# How could I know a font is a ttc font or ttf font?

Tags: c++, windows, truetype

I know the font family, and I want to know whether the font is a ttc font or a ttf font, how can I know that?

Comment: Did you tried by file extension? you can find the font in C:\windows\fonts\ and check file extension.

Comment: @SHR Does File Extension exactly work? I doubt it.

Comment: There are two font extensions: `ttc` and `ttf`, you just need to check.

Comment: @SHR Could I use “ttcf” table to determin whether the font is a ttc or ttf after I get the font data by using GetFontData?